# Why I am not able send id to backend and delete item by findByIdAndRemove()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

I want to remove item from mongodb. I fetched all items to one page. Then I am using map() to put items to cards. One Item is in card and contain edit btn and delete btn, delete btn has id (item.id). I grabed this id and send to backend and by this id delete item, but I am getting undefined of id..

```
const deletehandler = async (id) => {
  console.log(typeof id, id) // I am getting id = string
  
  try {
     await axios.delete('/api/delete', id)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  } 
}

return ( ...
{
 getData.map(item => {
          return (
            <>
              <div key={item.name} className='card'>
                <span className='ps-2'>{item.name}</span>
               
                  <RiDeleteBin5Line style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}
                      onClick={() => deletehandler(item._id)}/>
                
              </div>
}
```

api/delete folder :

```
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import db from "@/utils/db";
import User from "@/modules/User";


const handler = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body) // ===> here I am getting undefine 


  await db.connect();
  await User.findByIdAndRemove(id)
  await db.disconnect(); 
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'success '})
};

export default handler
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike axios.post() and axios.put(), the 2nd param to axios.delete() is the Axios options, not the request body. To send a request body with a DELETE request, you should use the data option.

```
const deletehandler = async (id) => {
  console.log(typeof id, id) // I am getting id = string
  
  try {
     await axios.delete('/api/delete', { data: {id} });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  } 
}
```

> https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/delete